# How to avoid Duplicates on PayPal plans

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am looking for a way to avoid the same user to resubscribe to the same PayPal plan. I have a landing page which is not demand from the user any input - no login, email or other info - and via this page the user can purchase a subscription.

Is there a away to setup the plan that way that a PayPal user can be active subscribed to a plan only once?

Comment: How could you stop it as you know nothing about the person making the subscription. I am tempted to say if they are nice enough to subscribe more than once, let them

Comment: Haha yeah but not fair... I was hopping that there is a param on the plan creation that disallow the duplicates. PayPal has all the details needed to do so. Agreement ID which is allocated to a Plan..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal will not keep track of whether a user has already subscribed to a plan, and prevent them from subscribing multiple times. If you need that feature, you must implement it yourself.

Comment: I thought so but wasn't sure. I was hopping that I missed something.. Adding more checks it is then. Thanks